# Infinite Scroll with turbo-rails and vanilla js do not refresh data-fslightbox to add more images to gallery

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7, turbo-rails

I am using turbo-rails to implement post's infinite scroll.
This posts have images and I use vanilla js to provider a good visualization of images as showed bellow:

```
<%= link_to file, 'data-fslightbox': "gallery" do %>
  <%= image_tag file, class: 'img-fluid', loading: 'lazy' %>
<% end %>
```

The gallery works well at the "first page", but the next pages, the "gallery" does not work.

Anyone may help me about it?